# How to find the weakest point of a model?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, print-strength, terminology, analysis

I would like to use some kind of simulation software to test my model and find the weakest points for example when pressed or stretches from different angles or positions. Under different loads or conditions, temperature or humidity.

How is such analysis called and are generic properties for example for PLA accurate enough for all PLA or is a very narrow and specific profile of material properties and print settings required, does such simulation software exist?

I simply want to find the weakest point of a model and perhaps get suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: I know that Fusion 360 has some structural analysis built-in but don't know to what extent it does it. It would at least give you a start and something to research.

Comment: Structural analysis on models is known as Finite Element Modeling or FEM, but since models are sliced with infill this needs to be modelled. This is difficult for composites and even more difficult for plastics. Not an easy task without knowledge of FEM or structural analysis. https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=FEM+ Furthemore, ti highly depends on the quality of your printer, too much cooling will mess up the optimal bonding between layers and your whole analysis goes south.

Comment: There are procedural methods, e.g. with OpenSCAD, to generate a STL file with explicit infill from the original solid STL. However, since infill provides very little strength, it would probably suffice to just hollow out the model to the intended wall thickness you will print at, and perform the FEM using that.